# Manual urban airship call to UAAppIntegration.userNotificationCenter need to call completionHandler?

Tags: ios, swift, urbanairship.com

we pass the appdelegate completion handler to urbanairship and call the appdelegate completion handler at the end

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void) {
    UAAppIntegration.userNotificationCenter(center, didReceive: response, withCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
    completionHandler()
}
```

or we call the appdelegate completion handler within the urbanairship completion

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void) {
    UAAppIntegration.userNotificationCenter(center, didReceive: response) {
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

or we just pass the completion to urbanairship (then if we have code we need to call it before the call to the one from urbanairship ?)

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void) {
    UAAppIntegration.userNotificationCenter(center, didReceive: response, withCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do either the 2nd or 3rd option. The completion handler should only be called once. Check out the [docs](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios/#automatic-integration) for all the places that you have to call through to UA and an example.

Comment: I figured, but since it's a black box one they don't say if they will call the completion handler if they do handle something or if we handle something we should not foward it to urban ?

Comment: The SDK is open source, so its not really a black box. The callback will always be called by UA.